# Unexpectedly short Perl slices

Tags: perl, list, slice

The following snippet of Perl is supposed to print the first 5 items of an array referenced by a hash value, or fewer if the array is shorter.

```
while ( my ($key,$value) = each %groups ) {
   print "$key: \n";
   my @list = grep defined, @{$value};
   my @slice = grep defined, @list[0..4];
   foreach my $item ( @slice ) {
      print "   $item \n";
   }
   print "   (", scalar @slice, " of ", scalar @list, ")\n";
}
```

I don't think the first `grep defined` is necessary, but it can't do any harm, and it should guarantee that there are no undefined array members before the slice. The second `grep defined` is to remove undefined array members in the result of `slice` when `@list` is shorter than 5.

`%groups` has been populated by repeated invocations of:

```
  $groups{$key} = () unless defined $groups{$key};
  push @{$groups{$key}}, $value;
```

Most of the time it works fine:

```
key1:
   value1
   value2
   value3
   value4
   value5
   (5 of 100)
```

But sometimes -- and I haven't worked out under what circumstances -- I see:

```
key2:
   value1
   (1 of 5)

key3:
   value1
   value2
   (2 of 5)
```

I expect the length of the printed list, and `x` from `(x of y)` to be `min(5,y)`

What could cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `grep` with an array slice for `@list` autovivifies the elements and extends the array.

```
@foo = (1,2,3);
@bar = @foo[0..9999];
print scalar @foo;             # =>  3

@foo = (1,2,3);
@bar = grep 1, @foo[0..9999];
print scalar @foo;             # => 10000
```

This also happens in other contexts where Perl wants to loop over an array slice.

```
@foo = (1,2,3);
foreach (@foo[0..9999]) { }
print scalar @foo;             # => 10000

@foo = (1,2,3);
@bar = map { } @foo[0..9999];
print scalar @foo;             # => 10000
```

---

So what are the workarounds?

1. Use a more complicated expression for the range or the `grep` operand

   ```
   @bar = grep 1, @foo[0..(@foo>=9999?9999:$#foo)];
   @bar = grep 1, @foo>=9999 ? @foo[0..9999] : @foo;
   ```
2. Use a temporary array variable

   ```
   @bar = grep 1, @tmp=@foo[0..9999]
   ```
3. (suggested by @FMc) use `map` to set up an intermediate array

   ```
   @bar = grep 1, map { $list[$_] } 0..9999;
   ```
4. work with array indices rather than directly with the array

   ```
   @bar_indices = grep defined($foo[$_]), 0..9999;
   @bar = @foo[@bar_indices];

   @bar = @foo[  grep defined($foo[$_]), 0..9999 ];
   ```

Comment: Ouch! Is there an idiomatic (or at least neat) way around it?

Comment: I'm thinking about it. [`no autovivification`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autovivification) doesn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: `print "   (", scalar @slice, " of ", scalar (grep defined, @list), ")\n";` achieves the right output. Might leave a gotcha for future maintainers though.

Comment: `my @slice = grep defined, map $list[$_], 0..3;`

Comment: Not often I accept an answer within 11 minutes of posting, but well deserved in this case I think. Thanks.

Comment: Option 4) is the most DWIM in my opinion. Specifying an array slice of five elements means that one is sure that the array has at least 5 elements.